# Getting Current Date and Time into 2 different variables in C Programming

Tags: c, date, time

What I am trying to do is to get the current system date and time and have them saved to two different variables so I can compare them later on with other dates and times. Here is the code I have so far. I issue is when I run the code I keep getting the same system time, and it is not correct, but the date is correct.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

time_t raw;
time(&raw);

struct tm *time_ptr;
time_ptr = localtime(&raw);

char current_date[11];
char current_time [20];
strftime(current_date, sizeof(current_date), "%m/%d/%Y", time_ptr);
strftime(current_time, sizeof(current_time), "%H:%I", time_ptr);

printf("Date Variable is: %s\n", current_date);
printf("Time Variable is: %s\n", current_time);

}
```

Comment: Note that according to POSIX, using `%X` with [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) gives you the locale-appropriate time, `%x` gives you the locale-appropriate date, and `%T` gives you the same as `%H:%M:%S`.  You can decide for yourself whether the Y2K-non-compliant `%D` — equivalent to `%m/%d/%y` is any use; IMO, it should be taken out to the back of the woodshed and buried.  OTOH, `%F` gives the same as `%Y-%m-%d` which definitely has its uses where people can understand it.  Not everyone will accept that — score one for `%x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format string for the time.

The `%I` format specifier gives you the hour in the range 01-12.  So `%H:%I` gives you the hour twice: first in 24 hour format then 12 hour format.

If you want minutes and seconds, you need to use `%M` and `%S` respectively.

```
strftime(current_time, sizeof(current_time), "%H:%M:%S", time_ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`"%H:%I"` is wrong format, you need `"%H:%M"` instead - with `%M` specifier for minute.

Refer to C11 standard

> 7.27.3.5 The strftime function

```
    #include <time.h>
    size_t strftime(char * restrict s,
         size_t maxsize,
         const char * restrict format,
         const struct tm * restrict timeptr);
```

> 3. Each conversion specifier is replaced by appropriate characters as described in the following list.
>
> > %M
> >     is replaced by the minute as a decimal number (00-59). [tm_min]